# JMeter CLI report generation fails - org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "json"

Tags: json, jmeter, load-testing

JMeter 5.3

I use the CLI as follows:

```
C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxxLTD\Guy\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin>jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\DCS DB threaded test.jmx"  -l"C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\db_report.csv" -Jthreads=5 -Jloops=100 -e -o"C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\output\19082020\"
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\DCS DB threaded test.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Wed Aug 26 14:22:56 IDT 2020 (1598440976507)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Generate Summary Results +     91 in 00:00:03 =   32.0/s Avg:    35 Min:     0 Max:  1031 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 2 Finished: 0
summary +     91 in 00:00:03 =   32.1/s Avg:    35 Min:     0 Max:  1031 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 2 Finished: 0
summary + 104409 in 00:00:29 = 3621.4/s Avg:     1 Min:     0 Max:   448 Err: 50400 (48.27%) Active: 0 Started: 5 Finished: 5
summary = 104500 in 00:00:32 = 3299.8/s Avg:     1 Min:     0 Max:  1031 Err: 50400 (48.23%)
Generate Summary Results + 104409 in 00:00:29 = 3620.9/s Avg:     1 Min:     0 Max:   448 Err: 50400 (48.27%) Active: 0 Started: 5 Finished: 5
Generate Summary Results = 104500 in 00:00:32 = 3299.1/s Avg:     1 Min:     0 Max:  1031 Err: 50400 (48.23%)
Tidying up ...    @ Wed Aug 26 14:23:28 IDT 2020 (1598441008843)
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "json" is unable to export data.
... end of run
```

At the end, you can see we have:

```
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "json" is unable to export data.
... end of run
```

Note that it didn't matter whether the report's extension was CSV or JTL.

I *was* able to generate the JTL report, and then run `jmeter -g <my JTL file>`, but I'd like the `-e` option to work.

Update: Now I get errors with the `g` option:

```
C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxLTD\Guy\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin>jmeter -g "C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\db_report" -o"C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\output\19082020\"
An error occurred: Data exporter "json" is unable to export data.
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is what I found in the `jmeter.log` file:

```
2020-08-26 14:37:51,812 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): nameFilter produced 1567500 samples
2020-08-26 14:37:51,812 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): dateRangeFilter produced 313500 samples
2020-08-26 14:37:51,812 INFO o.a.j.r.p.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer#stopProducing(): normalizer produced 104500 samples
2020-08-26 14:37:51,813 INFO o.a.j.r.p.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 104500 samples produced in 6s 70 ms on channel 0
2020-08-26 14:37:51,813 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'json' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter'
2020-08-26 14:37:51,814 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Found data for consumer statisticsSummary in context
2020-08-26 14:37:51,814 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for overall
2020-08-26 14:37:51,815 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for other transactions
2020-08-26 14:37:51,815 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Checking output folder
2020-08-26 14:37:51,816 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "json" is unable to export data.
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:385) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:258) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:545) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:252) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.3]
Caused by: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ExportException: Error creating output folder C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - Nayax LTD\Guy\JMeter\output\19082020" 
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.checkAndGetOutputFolder(JsonExporter.java:112) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:77) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:379) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxxLTD\Guy\JMeter\output\19082020" 
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2491) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.checkAndGetOutputFolder(JsonExporter.java:110) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:77) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:379) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    ... 7 more
```

So it all started from:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\Users\guyl\OneDrive - xxx LTD\Guy\JMeter\output\19082020"
```

It's supposed to create that folder if it doesn't exist, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this error as well and the solution to my problem was that from this command:

jmeter -n -t “location of test file” -l “location of your result file” -e -o “location of reports folder”

The third option "location of reports folder" needed to be a brand new non-existing folder. After telling the command to create a folder, my HTML reports were successful!

Answer (score 3):

JMeter will create only 1 level of folder and not the full hierarchy.

Second , try avoiding a folder with spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced the same error message, using jMeter 5.4.1.

In my case, I ended up investigating the problem using [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Procmon showed that the closing double quote " was included in the folder path, which is an invalid character in windows folder/file names.

I was fortunate enough that my path did not have any spaces in it so removing the double quote did not impact me. Try to use folders without spaces in the names, or alternatively use the 8.3 [short names](https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file) in the paths instead.